# Django: How to migrate primary key to BigIntegerField of class that inherits from AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-migrations, dbmigrate

I have a Django project that has numerous applications. Each application has a `models.py` file.

I'm using [**this strategy**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558821/how-to-replace-djangos-primary-key-with-a-different-integer-that-is-unique-for/37605582#37605582) to modify all the models in my project such that their primary keys are explicitly defined as `id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)` instead of implicitly defined as `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)`

This strategy is working well for most of my models. Except there is a problem with one model. It is my `Profile` model defined below:

```
class Profile(CachingMixin, AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=254,null=False, blank=False,)
```

I add the following line to this model:

```
id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

After that, I successfully run the `manage.py makemigrations`. A new migration file gets created. However, when I apply this migration, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1833, "Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'profiles_prof_profile_id_59a0cf98572a1aaa_fk_profiles_profile_id' of table 'myapp_db.profiles_profile_groups'")
```

How can I remedy this problem? Clearly it has something to do with inheriting from `AbstractUser`. Because `Profile` inherits from the `AbstractUser` class, it comes with its own baggage: 2 child tables: `profiles_profile_group` and `profiles_profile_user_permissions`. Each of those two child tables have a column `profile_id` which points back to the parent table's primary key. Those two columns are INT. So when I change the parent's primary key to BIGINT, it breaks. What is the solution here?

Comment: are the two other tables in question part of your own code or does it come from an app?

Comment: I didn't create those two other tables.

Comment: Is the profile table part of your code? Can you name the app you use for profiles?

Comment: The app name: `profiles`. Class name `Profile`. Here is what gets created in the Database: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UFylbhbG2eTmh4TWFuNnBCRDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You will  have to change all the models at once. Might even need to edit the migrations file.