# Django how to create URL pattern to identify an object

Tags: python, django, model

I am developing a Django app which includes some user profiles. (Profile is a custom model).

I want to implement the Profile in such a way so that I can access a page e.g `localhost:8080/profile/234332` where `234332` is a random number.

I am not sure how to handle this unique identifier for each profile, shall I tried something like

```
id=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

This gives a way too long string but I wanted to be if possible a number of 5-8 digits. My concern is how to implement this field in such way so that will never be two profiles with the same ID.

Comment: why not use django generated pk.  It isn't random, but it auto increments so no two are the same

Comment: Exposing the PK isn't risky?

Comment: How is it riskier than making up your own numbers?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37605582/267540