# Generate numbers in order for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on creating a forum (just to test) and i've reached the point where i sync the thread lists and the posts inside. I've relied on the `AUTO INCREMENT` in mysql to sync them but i understand that it won't be useful in the future.

My question is now, how would i generate a random number stacking just like the mysql `auto_increment` ?

For viewing the thread list, it's currently

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM threads WHERE th_unique='$section';
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);`

and then i just fetch the data and output the threads in the list.

Basicly, how would i generate a number just like Auto increment when a insert query is sent?

I am aware of `rand()` but i don't find it effective in the end due to the fact that it might overlap and use the same number that already exists.

Comment: [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid), but what exactly is your problem with `AUTO INCREMENT`?

Comment: If you're using InnoDB as your engine for the table, why not just do this as a transaction?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with `auto_increment` and why can't you use it in the future and how does the random number help you solve the issue? There's also a MySQL function called `UUID()`. If you worry about exposing numeric identifiers to the public, you can always encrypt them or encode them with `Hashids` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can use [AUTO_INCREMENT with replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html) under certain conditions.

> Statement-based replication of AUTO_INCREMENT, LAST_INSERT_ID(), and
>   TIMESTAMP values is done correctly, subject to the following
>   exceptions:
>
> When using statement-based replication prior to MySQL 5.7.1,
>   AUTO_INCREMENT columns in tables on the slave must match the same
>   columns on the master; that is, AUTO_INCREMENT columns must be
>   replicated to AUTO_INCREMENT columns. ...

And the list goes on. If your situation is one of the conditions where AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't work [UUID](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/) is an option.

Also take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605582/267540  it's for python/django Here's what it looks like when translated to PHP

```
define('START_TIME',1470825057000);

function make_id() {
    /**
     * inspired by http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram
     * Generates a unique identifier that isn't too complex and has a sequential nature (sort of)
     */

    $t = microtime(True)*1000 - START_TIME;

    $rnd = random_int(0,8388607);
    return ($t << 23) | $rnd;

}

function reverse_id($id) {
    $id = ($id >> 23) + START_TIME;
    return $id;
}

for ($counter=0; $counter<100; $counter++) {
    $id = make_id() ;
    $time = reverse_id($id);
    print "$id  $time \n"; 
}
print 'Ending time     ' . microtime(True)*1000;
```

As you can see the number look sequential but they are still safe for replication.

Comment: Yea, that looks like something i'd want to use, if you can covert it, you're the best