# How to get specific value from this function?

Tags: python

I read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605582/6426449

```
START_TIME = a constant that represents a unix timestamp

def make_id():

    t = int(time.time()*1000) - START_TIME
    u = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(23)
    id = (t << 23 ) | u

    return id

def reverse_id(id):
    t  = id >> 23
    return t + START_TIME
```

From above def, How to get `t` and `u` of `id`(It's generated from `def make_id`)?

Like

```
def get_t(id):
    some methods
    return t

def get_u(id):
    some methods
    return u
```

Comment: You can't. Why would you want to?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why can't you? It was created by shifting and ORing, you can undo it by shifting and masking.

Comment: Well, obviously you can write a function to do the opposite of what those do, but OP seems to want to access the actual variables inside the existing functions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Where do you see that? The question says he wants to get them from the value of `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `t`, just undo the left shift with a right shift.

```
def get_t(id):
    return id >> 23
```

To get `u`, use a bit mask with the rightmost 23 bits set

```
def get_u(id):
    return id & 0x7fffff
```