# python3.4, unsupported operand type(s) for <<, How can I fix it?

Tags: python

I read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605582/6426449

and this part occurred an error

```
START_TIME = time.time() #at some time

def make_id():

    t = int(time.time()*1000) - START_TIME
    u = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(23)
    id = (t << 23 ) | u #This part has problem

    return id
```

`unsupported operand type(s) for <<`

Can't I use this operation `<<`?

Or How can I use `<<`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `t` an integer, note the parenthesis:

```
 t = int(time.time()*1000 - START_TIME)
```

Your version:

```
t = int(time.time()*1000) - START_TIME
```

makes `t`  a float because `START_TIME` is a float.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this line

```
t = int(time.time()*1000) - START_TIME
```

casts `t` to a float (I guess because `START_TIME` is a float). You cannot, however, apply bitwise shifting to a float, so try this instead

```
import time
import random

START_TIME = time.time() #at some time

def make_id():

    t = int(time.time()*1000) - START_TIME
    u = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(23)
    id = (int(t) << 23 ) | u #Note the explicit INT() here

    return id

print(make_id())
```