# What is the best index for postgresql timestamp

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have searched a lot but has not found the answer for the following question. I have a table with lots of record (in the order of 100M) and I want to run the following query on it :

```
Entity.objects.filter(creation_time__gte=some_date).order_by('id').all()[0]
```

and my table is something like follows :

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Other fields
```

Comment: I guess output is not supposed to be precise, so why not to sort by serial id? In simple cases will give almost the same order. After that you may continue filtering by date if you need to.

Comment: That should be a simple B-tree index on `creation_time`, right?

Comment: I want minimum ID of my objects that are created after some special time. I don't what minimum ID of whole objects

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe with b_tree query is still very very slow and takes tens of minutes to perform

Comment: Please describe your task in the question. Not solution. What is the "special time", why "minimum ID" and so on.

Comment: by "special time" I mean some_date, for example a week ago.

Comment: Also in my query I'm sorting by id and getting the first one. So minimum ID! @IvanStarostin

Comment: if you handle a lot of dates check out https://www.timescale.com/

Comment: @mohammad Then find out the SQL query, collect `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for it and add the result to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What should I exactly run? running only `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` raises error

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...`. For that, you need to figure out the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: did you try to remove `all`  `Entity.objects.filter(creation_time__gte=some_date).order_by('id')[0]`

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what database you run this against and what index that you use on the creation_time field this query is likely to be slow. Why? Because your filter is an inequality and not an equality and you are combining that with a sort, think about it in a worst case scenario you could be sorting 99 million records.

One approach that you could use is to create a non serial primary key that is derived from creation time. Sort of like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605582/267540

You could create a BTREE creation time and then do a query that filters further with an upper limit

```
Entity.objects.filter(creation_time__gte=some_date
    ).filter(creation_time__lt=some_other_date).order_by('id').all()[0]
```

And lastly you could do a query that use '[only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only)' to fetch only the primary key, that would be an index only query for postgresql and could lead to a slight speed up.

Comment: With the link you provided (first solution) how can I do my query?

Comment: that would have to be posted as a separate question.