# How can I use a 64-bit id in Django using Postgres as a backend?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to create a 64-bit id in Django (3.1), somewhat like [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605582), and store it in Postgres (13.1).

For reference, here is their proposed Django model:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(default = fields.make_id, primary_key=True)
```

with their `make_id` modified to return a 64-bit integer with the highest bit set:

```
def make_id():
    return 13528776667777991352
```

If I use this proposal, I get an error when trying `instance.save()`:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: bigint out of range
```

That seems correct to me.  That number has the highest bit set:

```
$ python -c "print(f'{13528776667777991352:>64b}')"
1011101110111111110111101011001101101000100000000000001010111000
```

It will be too large for a signed 64-bit int, but not too large for unsigned:

```
$ python -c "print(13528776667777991352 > (2**63-1))"
True
$ python -c "print(13528776667777991352 < 2**64)"
True
```

Postgres docs [say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html) the range of `bigint` is `-2**63` to `2**63-1`.  (The numbers in the docs are -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807.)

I am surprised that no one commented on that stackoverflow answer.  Since time is shifted into the highest bit position, I feel like anyone would hit this right away.  I may be missing something obvious.

I've thought of a few options.

1. Write a [Django custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields) (say "UnsignedBigIntegerField") that slides the number from [`-2**63`, `2**63-1`] to [0, `2**64`] by adding `2**63` when it gets saved, and subtracting that when it gets loaded.  A hack to be sure.
2. Write a Django custom field that wraps some other Postgres type, like a [byte string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-binary.html) or [bitfield](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-bit.html), or [fixed-precision numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).

How can I use a 64-bit id in Django 3.1 using Postgres 13.1 as a backend?

This will be used as an id, so Postgres lookups should be as fast and efficient as possible.

**EDIT**: My current solution is to leave the highest bit unset. So, I have a 63-bit id.  That fits Postgres's constraint, and is fairly simple.  It is annoying that I have to leave a bit on the table.

Comment: Correct Postgres does not support unsigned integers, so you are limited  to 2^63- 1 values. But lets put that in perspective are you really "leaving a bit on the table".   If you had started consuming a sequence at midnight on 2020-01-01 at the rate of 10M/sec you run out around 21:00  on 13-Sep-31248 (give or take a century).  You could set up a the sequence to roll over to the most negative value thus giving the full 64bit range. [Just for fun](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9f3c2b7b57d45215f391faff3b635fc6).